# how to input this for Dijkstra algorithm question

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I have an assignment on Dijkstra's algorithm, but the question has me confused about the input. It asks me to find shortest and second shortest paths, and that part I have figured out, but how do I even start with the graph has me troubled. 
The question says the input has to be read from a file and the file contains the number of nodes and the weight between two nodes. Weight between two nodes should be 1 to 9, and can use 0 to indicate a path that doesn't exist.
Now my question is what has to be the contents of the file? I was able to understand Dijkstra's algorithm where the input was a 2d array that represents the graph. Can someone clarify what is expected from this question? Like what the source file should contain.

Comment: I think input format should be defined in the assignment, there are many ways how to represent a graph..

Comment: @Ecto The input is read from a file and contains the number of nodes and the weight between two nodes. Weight between two nodes should be within 1 to 9. You may use 0 to indicate a path that doesn’t exist.
This is what the assignment says for input format. That's it.

Comment: Do you create the file on your own?

Comment: @Ecto Yes........

Comment: @wakanada you can represent a weighted Graph as a Matrix, where the entry `(i,j)` is the weight between Node `i` and `j`. When it is an undirected graph it is a symmetrical matrix. If there is no path from `i` to `j` use 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably supposed to create file like this:
(example - there are many ways to do it)

```
4   # number of nodes (from 1 to 4)
1 2 3   # means edge from node 1 to node 2 with weight 3
2 3 1   # means edge from node 2 to node 3 with weight 1
...
```

this would correspond to 2d matrix like this:

```
0 3 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```